# Single job store, single started scheduler and multiple read-only worker processes

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I ran into this FAQ indicating that sharing a persistent job store among two or more processes will lead to incorrect scheduler behavior:

[How do I share a single job store among one or more worker processes?](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes)

`My question is`: If there's only a single worker scheduler that has been started via .start(), and another scheduler process is initialized on the same persistent sqlite jobstore only to print the trigger of a certain `job_id` (won't invoke a .start()), could that lead to cases of incorrect scheduler behavior?

Using `apscheduler 3.6.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First of all, the scheduler has to be started for it to return you the list of permanently stored jobs. Another potential issue is that the current APScheduler version deletes any jobs on retrieval for which it cannot find the corresponding task function. This behavior was initially added to clear out obsolete jobs, but was in retrospect ill conceived and will be removed in v4.0.

On the upside, it is possible to start the scheduler in paused mode so it won't try to run any jobs but will still give you the list of jobs, so long as all the target functions are importable.